# like condtion in sqldatasource for oracle database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

i have an sqldatasource for a grid to query data from oracle database. everything works fine and dandy till i run into a problem with the where clause with "like" condition. below is the command i would like to pass into the datasource.

```
ssql = "select * from table1 where lastname like upper('%' || :last_name || '%')"
sqldatasource.selectparameters.add("last_name","test")
```

but no matter what i do it keeps saying invalid variable name/number. can someone help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something that you can do in the code to escape the %, but you could always avoid the issue by changing the sql statement to use chr(37) instead of '%'. E.g.:

```
select * from dual
where 'ABXD' like chr(37)||'X'||chr(37);
```

(I'd comment the code heavily to make it clear why you've done that, if you do end up choosing this route, though!)

Comment: i still got the same error and this is not my code.